# Float to int in haskell

Tags: haskell

In this Haskell code:

```
power a r = [a*(truncate (r**i)) | i <- e]
    where e = [0,10]
```

I am getting an error with the `**` operation because I believe it makes a float.
Is there a way to convert it to an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by getting an error since your code type-checks, but you probably want the `^` operator:

```
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
```

Your code type-checks just fine with that, too:

```
power a r = [a*(r^i) | i <- e]
    where e = [0,10]
```